# Excel vba, Do Until Loop that works with F8, but not full "run" Or with Win Scheduler

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with VBA in excel, this code works fine when i step through the sub with F8.
But when i run the whole script the loop continue for 7333 rows?!

```
Dim AgentCell As Long                                                     
AgentCell = releaseCalls.Sheets("samtal").Range("A" & MyLastAgent).Row + 1                    
Do Until IsEmpty(Range("B" & AgentCell).Value) = True
    releaseCalls.Sheets("samtal").Range("A" & AgentCell).Value = D
    MyLastAgent = releaseCalls.Sheets("samtal").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    AgentCell = releaseCalls.Sheets("samtal").Range("B" & MyLastAgent).Row + 1
Loop
```

Anyone seen this?

Comment: `Do Until IsEmpty(releaseCalls.Sheets("samtal").Range("B" & AgentCell).Value) = True`

Comment: Oh, My, god.. It worked. I love you.
I've tried so hard to figure this out.
So i just had to have the whole path to where, but how come it sort of worked?

Comment: note `releaseCalls.Sheets("samtal").Range("B" & MyLastAgent).Row` is the same as `MyLastAgent`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? MyLasAgent is only the number of the row?

Comment: @Bowman  Yes, the row number of Range("B" & n) is always n.

Comment: As you probably figured out by now, I’m not a programmer:) so I don’t get it, It do work now though.